# can I mount Hadoop Linux server path to another non hadoop linux server path?

Tags: unix, sshfs

can I mount Hadoop Linux server local path (NON HDFS) to another non hadoop linux server path

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You question has nothing to do with Hadoop. It's about mounting remote directory on local Linux machine.

There are different options, you can try **SSHFS**. You can read more about it in this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh)